# Magento 2 do not use taxes when the customer is a company from another country

Tags: magento2, orders, tax, vat

I'd like to know the happy path in magento 2 for following scenario

1. I have a shop in germany which ships to other, EU countries.
2. When you order as a company from another country, let's say France and you provide your VAT-Id, the order has to be calculcated excluding VAT.

How can I realize this with Magento 2 ? 
I tried to set up a specific customer group which is tax free, but this does not work on guest customers

thanks

Comment: I have same problem here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235429/magento2-b2b-without-tax-in-checkout - did you found solution?

Comment: Yes - I created a VAT free customer group for that